# Embedded Javascript interpreter for php

Tags: php, javascript, interpreter

Is there some api available for embedding javascript in php - something similar to Jint for .NET.

I would like to allow user to customize workflow by being able to access limited php classes and methods that can be run at server-side.

User writes a code block that gets executed later... for example, js/ecma script code like ...

```
if (Contact.Age < 12){
  Contact.setEligibility = false;
}
else{
  Contact.setEligibility = true;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid to directly expose script execution to the client.  Didn't really evaluate that as an option.  Thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a pseudo-Javascript interpreter called 'phpjs' (php functions implemented in javascript), which I happen to know about. And a fully syntax compatible JS interpreter (written in pure PHP) called **Javascript for PHP5**: http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/ - implements the JS language, not the DOM or much functions.

If you want a full-fledged and "real" Javascript runtime, then there is a PECL extension for that. http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey (requires custom compiling PHP interpreter).

Comment: worth pointing out that both the above are alpha releases, so not production quality. j4p5 looks interesting but appears not to have been updated in several years; project may be dead. The spidermonkey one is more recent but the homepage link is dead. I don't think I'd want to use either for anything serious.

Comment: Thanks, mario.  Appreciate your help.